# Android Specifications : What are the integer values for "small" screen size, "normal" screen size, ldpi, mdpi, hdpi?

Tags: unity, android, resolution, aspect-ratio

Android has this document where they define thee terms for screen size, and pixel density such as ***screenSize="small", "ldpi"***. Here is the link to that document:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution

Here is the section of definitions:

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

But, I don't know the **specific integer values** for "small" screen size, "normal" screen size, ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi from that document.  Can anyone please tell me the integer values of these terms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropping `android:screenDensity="ldpi"` into the site search at the official [Android development site](https://developer.android.com) gives the [screen densities reference](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) as the second hit which in turn provides the table for the pixel densities qualifiers

Table 1. Configuration qualifiers for different pixel densities.

| Density qualifier | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ldpi | Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi). |
| mdpi | Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.) |
| hdpi | Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi). |
| xhdpi | Resources for extra-high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi). |
| xxhdpi | Resources for extra-extra-high-density (xxhdpi) screens (~480dpi). |
| xxxhdpi | Resources for extra-extra-extra-high-density (xxxhdpi) uses (~640dpi). |
| nodpi | Resources for all densities. These are density-independent resources. The system does not scale resources tagged with this qualifier, regardless of the current screen's density. |
| tvdpi | Resources for screens somewhere between mdpi and hdpi; approximately 213dpi. This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it—providing mdpi and hdpi resources is sufficient for most apps and the system will scale them as appropriate. If you find it necessary to provide tvdpi resources, you should size them at a factor of 1.33*mdpi. For example, a 100px x 100px image for mdpi screens should be 133px x 133px for tvdpi. |

Dropping `screen android:screenSize="small"` into a general web search brought me to [Alvin Alexander's blog post on Android screen sizes](https://alvinalexander.com/android/android-screen-sizes-dimensions-xlarge-large-normal-small/), with the following info:

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Or with more digging at the Android dev site, you can find the same info [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/configuration) about a third of the way down (or search that same page for `SCREENSIZE_SMALL`).

Most of this information is also available in the Stack Overflow post [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices).

Comment: I know that **dpi means dot per inch**.  Can you please explain what **dp** stand for ? Thanks.

Comment: **dp** is defined & explained in the screen densities reference doc linked near the top of the answer. I'll see about making an edit summarizing that info, but in the mean time, refer to the documentation as it gives an example, illustration & conversion formula.

Comment: Here is the definition: **px = dp * (dpi / 160)**.  Here is the link to an answer from StackOverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144388/difficulty-to-understand-how-to-support-multiple-screen